# Python error "Couldn't find Porcupine's keyword file" in the Picovoice library

Tags: python, python-3.x

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynZCX.png)

I copied the code from the picovoice documentation, entered everything as indicated, checked on several .ppm files anyway it doesn't work

```
from picovoice import Picovoice

def wake_word_callback():
    # wake word detected
    pass

def inference_callback(inference):
   if inference.is_understood:
      intent = inference.intent
      slots = inference.slots
      # take action based on intent and slot values
   else:
      # unsupported command
      pass

try:
    picovoice = Picovoice(
        access_key="${MwLL6aWXSBHw1X/PIMQEAWQXuAIyvvwoYc3QXhinnHb/7VP+IOCGYQ==}",
        keyword_path=r"${C:\Users\tim\PycharmProjects\Jarvis2.0\jarvis_windows.ppn}",
        wake_word_callback=wake_word_callback,
        context_path=r"${C:\Users\tim\PycharmProjects\Jarvis2.0\alarm_windows.rhn}",
        inference_callback=inference_callback)
except PicovoiceError as e:
    pass
def get_next_audio_frame():
    pass

while True:
    audio_frame = get_next_audio_frame()
    picovoice.process(audio_frame)
picovoice.delete()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tim\PycharmProjects\Jarvis2.0\.venv\ActivationPhrase.py", line 17, in <module>
    picovoice = Picovoice(
  File "C:\Users\tim\PycharmProjects\Jarvis2.0\.venv\lib\site-packages\picovoice\_picovoice.py", line 162, in __init__
    raise ValueError("Couldn't find Porcupine's keyword file at '%s'." % keyword_path)
ValueError: Couldn't find Porcupine's keyword file at '${C:\Users\tim\PycharmProjects\Jarvis2.0\jarvis_windows.ppn}'.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tim\PycharmProjects\Jarvis2.0\.venv\ActivationPhrase.py", line 23, in <module>
    except PicovoiceError as e:
NameError: name 'PicovoiceError' is not defined
```

I copied the code from the picovoice documentation, entered everything as indicated, checked on several .ppm files anyway it doesn't work